# How to make non-root usr able to use mount "-o" options?

Tags: linux, mount

It's on my debian 9.4 system, linux 4.9 which I have full access to it(including root access and hardware access).

I created an user and wanted to mount a overlay2 filesystem in its home dir. However, it was denied because only `root` can use mount "-o" option.

I don't want to use sudo to do this, because in that way this usr will be allowed to mount any filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to use `sudo` to do this, because in that way this usr will be allowed to mount any filesystem.

`sudo` is the correct tool for the job. You can specify options for a command in your `sudoers` file; this will only allow the command to be run with the exact options specified.